# Como retornar uma string do método que consulta SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Como fazer um método que retorne uma *string* com um único resultado?

Estou tentando algo assim:

```
public String getString(String var) {
    String selectQuery = 
           "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_STATUS+" WHERE "+KEY_STATUS_KEY+"='"+var+"' LIMIT 1";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //não sei como retornar a string
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode utilizar o [StringBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) ou o [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Fica um exemplo:

```
public String getString(String var) 
{       
    String selectQuery = 
        "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_STATUS+" WHERE "+KEY_STATUS_KEY+"='"+var+"' LIMIT 1";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    /*********** Fazer isto por cada coluna ***************/
    String nome_da_coluna_string = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex('nome_da_coluna'));

    sb.append(nome_da_coluna_string);
    /******************************************************/

    cursor.close();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Jorge B funcionou como esperado.